# Как перематывать аудиозапись с помощью Python

Tags: python, аудио, поиск-библиотек

Пишу аудиоплеер на Python. Хотел добавить функцию перемотки музыки. Подскажите как эту функцию можно реализовать? С помощью каких модулей это можно сделать?

```
import tkinter as tk 
import os 

from pygame import mixer 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

class MPlayer():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.init_main() 

    def init_main(self):
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/Play.png')
        label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
        label.pack()

        menuBar = tk.Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=menuBar)

        subMenu = tk.Menu(menuBar)
        menuBar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=subMenu)

        subMenu.add_cascade(label='Open', command=self.browse_file)
        subMenu.add_cascade(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)

        self.playPhoto = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'Images\Play-512.png')
        playBtn = tk.Button(root, image=self.playPhoto, command=self.play_music)
        playBtn.pack()

        scale = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient='horizontal', command=self.set_vol)
        scale.set(50)
        scale.pack()
        mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)

        self.statusBar = tk.Label(root, text='Welcome to MP', relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
        self.statusBar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)


    def browse_file(self):
        global filename 
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    def play_music(self):
        try:
            paused 
        except NameError:
            try:
                mixer.music.load(filename)
                mixer.music.play()
                self.statusBar['text'] = 'Playing music' + ' - ' + os.path.basename(filename)      
            except:
                messagebox.showerror('File not found!', 'Music Player couldn\'t find the file. Please, check again!')
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause() 
            statusbar['text'] = 'Music Resumed'

    def pause_music(self):
        global paused 
        paused = True 
        mixer.music.pause() 
        self.statusBar['text'] = 'Music Paused'

    def stop_music(self):
        mixer.music.stop() 
        self.statusBar['text'] = 'Music Stopped'

    def set_vol(self, value):
        volume = int(value) / 100 
        mixer.music.set_volume(volume)





if __name__=='__main__':

    mixer.init()

     root = tk.Tk() 
     app = Player(root)
     root.geometry('350x450')
     root.iconbitmap(r'Images\Music_29918.ico')
     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать пример простенького аудиоплеера ?

Comment: Зависит от того, как именно вы воспроизводите звук.

Comment: Вот весь код плеера, что-нибудь можете подсказать?

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать mixer.music.set_pos : https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos